# Not sure how to implement IEnumerable on this class

Tags: c#, api

Continuing to develop the API I have mentioned in previous posts, I have come across the following situation:

> I need to be able to access a list of responses returned by the
>   webservice.

Problem is I am unsure how to implement IEnumerable on this class.

```
...
public class ResponseBodyResponse
{
    public ResponseListResponse ResponseList { get; set; }

    public class ResponseListResponse 
    {
        public ResponseInfoResponse ResponseInfo { get; set; }

        public class ResponseInfoResponse 
        {
            public string RequestId { get; set; }
            public string RequestType { get; set; }
            public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
            public string RequestStatus { get; set; }
            public string Error { get; set; }
            public string Memo { get; set; }
        }

        public ResponseListResponse()
        {
            ResponseInfo = new ResponseInfoResponse();
        }
    }

    public ResponseBodyResponse()
    {
        ResponseList = new ResponseListResponse();
    }
...
```

Before anyone asks I did get a copy of the xsd files, however generating the classes using xsd.exe resulted in a ridiculous mishmash of files with conflicting class names causing over 1000 ambiguous naming errors.

Comment: If all your classes are beginning with 'Response' you should consider creating a namespace for it

Comment: I know it doesn't show here, but each API is broken into its own namespace : Reports, orders, inventory etc. Within each API is a series of classes for say getting order status in both a request/response fashion. ie GetReportStatusRequest and GetReportStatusResponse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should return a concrete collection such as a list or an array from a web service instead of an implementation `IEnumerable<T>`, even though lists and arrays (and other  colections) do implement it. Its not `IEnumerable<T>` that is the key for the serialization.

Aside, the nested class structure makes your code hard to consume.

Since I'm not sure of your intent with your above code, here is an example

```
public class Road 
{
    public Car[] Cars { get; set; } // this can be also `List<Car>`
}
public class Car
{
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: Are you able to provide an example?

Comment: I believe worth noting that this collection anyway woudl implement `IEnumerable<T>`, or not?

Comment: The nested class structure was suggested in a previous post. I am pretty new to OOP so I make no claim of expertise here :) If you have a better suggestion for the class structure I am all ears. In the mean time I will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: @DanielA.White http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419765/class-design-how-do-i-create-a-class-with-nested-objects